# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at removeFromParentNode() SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

I've got the following error popping up randomly during my game execution:

[image]

I am creating multiple instances of a carNode, at random moments in time, and all of them has this action of removing the node from the scene. Most of the time it is not a problem, but in some cases the app crashes with the error displayed in the photo. It seems like I could get the error in these cases:

An object is not initialized
An object is already released
Something else that is not very likely to happen

..excluding the first one, I'm more than sure that I am not releasing the object ahead of time.. so what could it be?

This is the complete code:

```
func spawnCarAtPosition(position: SCNVector3) {

    // Create a material using the model_texture.tga image
    let carMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    carMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "assets.scnassets/Textures/model_texture.tga")
    carMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = false

    // Create a clone of the Car node of the carScene - you need a clone because you need to add many cars
    var carNode: SCNNode!
    let randomNumb = AppDelegate().randRange(0, upper: beachCarArray.count -     1)
    let selectedObject = beachCarArray[randomNumb]
    carNode = selectedObject.objectscene.rootNode.childNodeWithName(selectedObject.objectname, recursively: false)!.clone() as SCNNode
    carNode.name = selectedObject.objectname
    carNode.position = position

    // Set the material
    carNode.geometry!.firstMaterial = carMaterial

    // x = length, y = height, z = width
    let xscale = 0.6
    let yscale = 0.8
    let zscale = 0.5
    carNode.scale = SCNVector3(xscale, yscale, zscale)

    // Create a physicsbody for collision detection
    let boundingBox = AppDelegate().sizeOfBoundingBoxFromNode(carNode)
    let carPhysicsBodyShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: CGFloat(boundingBox.width * Float(xscale)), height: CGFloat(boundingBox.height * Float(yscale)), length: CGFloat(boundingBox.depth * Float(zscale)), chamferRadius: 0.0), options: nil)

    carNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Kinematic, shape: carPhysicsBodyShape)
    carNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Car
    carNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    carNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player

    // Move the car
    let moveDirection: Float = position.x > 0.0 ? -1.0 : 1.0
    let moveDistance = levelData.gameLevelWidth()
    let moveAction = SCNAction.moveBy(SCNVector3(x: moveDistance * moveDirection, y: 0.0, z: 0.0), duration: Double(AppDelegate().randomBetweenNumbers(6.0, secondNum: 7.0)))
    let removeAction = SCNAction.runBlock { node -> Void in
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
    carNode.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([moveAction, removeAction]))

    // Rotate the car to move it in the right direction
    if moveDirection > 0.0 {
        carNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 3.1415)
    }

    // add node to screen
    rootNode.addChildNode(carNode)
}
```

EDIT:

Print of the object before crash:

```
<SCNNode: 0x1374e5ba0 'BeachCar_2' pos(1.500000 0.035000 -4.800000) rot(0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 3.141500) scale(0.600000 0.800000 0.500000) | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x135fe80c0 'BeachCar_2'> | no child>
```

With SCNAnimation remove action:
[image]

EDIT 2:

```
func createSpawnNode(gridPosition: SCNVector3, row: Int, parentNode: SCNNode)  {

        // Determine if the car should start from the left of the right
        let startCol = row % 2 == 0 ? 0 : data.columnCount() - 1
        let moveDirection : Float = row % 2 == 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0

        // Determine the position of the node
        var position = coordinatesForGridPosition(column: startCol, row: row)
        position = SCNVector3(x: position.x, y: GameVariables.gamePlaneHeight / 2, z: position.z)

        // Create node
        let spawnNode = SCNNode()
        spawnNode.position = position

        var spawnAction: SCNAction!
        var delayAction: SCNAction!

        // Create an action to make the node spawn cars
        spawnAction = SCNAction.runBlock({ node in
            self.spawnDelegate!.spawnCarAtPosition(node.position)
        })

        delayAction = SCNAction.waitForDuration(3.0, withRange: 2.0)
        spawnNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.sequence([spawnAction, delayAction])))

        parentNode.addChildNode(spawnNode)

        // record newly created node
        recordNodeAtRow(spawnNode, row: row)
    }
```

The parentNode is the rootNode of the Scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speculating...maybe something internal is holding a reference to `carNode` that lasts past your `removeFromParentNode()` call? Looks like there's a retain cycle: `carNode` holds a strong reference to `removeAction`, whose closure holds a (strong?) reference back to `carNode`.

I take the existence of `removeFromParentNode` on `SCNAction` to be a very big hint, though. It wouldn't be there if it weren't needed. Instead of a closure-based call, try

```
let removeAction = SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()
carNode.runAction(SCNAction.sequence([moveAction, removeAction]))
```

And just to make sure: you're invoking `spawnCarAtPosition()` from the main thread, not a background thread, right?

Edit after your EDIT 2:
`createSpawnNode()` was a bit confusing to read, because of your reuse of `position` (how about two `let` definitions instead of one `var`?) (the other two `var` defs would be more straightforward as `let`, btw). I don't see anything that I think would cause a crash.

Instead of copying the source Car's `objectName`, I'd give each node a unique name (maybe `NSDate().description`) to see if you can detect a pattern.

I'd also try moving the spawning out of an SCNAction, and into a render callback (probably `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`, in case you're tickling an internal SceneKit bug. You are invoking one `SCNAction` within another. Documentation is silent on whether that's allowed, but since you're seeing erratic behavior it seems like a good thing to simplify out.

I assume you've tried the standard tricks of turning on zombies, and setting an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Still crashes, but with a different error: 0x190d06314 <+40>:  ldr    x8, [x9, #80]

Comment: Interesting. Is there any chance the carNode has already been removed when the `removeFromParent` call is made? Or has never been attached? I wonder what would happen if you moved the `addChildNode()` call up a bit, before you call `runAction()`.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but there seems to be no difference. It still crashes with the second error.

Comment: Can we see how you're invoking `spawnCarAtPosition()`?

Comment: Thanks for all the help you're providing. I will try moving the call to spawnCarAtPosition somewhere else, but I don't think it could be a problem.. after the call is done at completion, shouldn't the code in the function execute independently?  I forgot to say that I create many spawnNode and every so often I remove them from parent and recreate them, but this should not affect in any way the carNode, shouldn't it?

Comment: The approach of using multiple logic-only nodes to randomly create other nodes seems overcomplicated to me. And it's not testable or reproducible, which is a problem when you're debugging a random crash. If you're seeing erratic behavior, simplify things and exclude possibilities until you can find the cause.

Comment: Seems like wrapping the call to the spawn function with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ }) avoids the crash. You were totally right in saying that the nested actions could have caused a problem.